# Unable to configure Send Email

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mulesoft, anypoint-studio, mule4

I am trying to add a send email functionality in my flow and when I try to place the Send from the Palette to the flow I get the below error

[image]

Hitting Ok in the above pop up and tried to create the Connector configuration

[image]

Nothing is happening, can anyone please suggest what is happening here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify that you have the right dependency for the Email connector in the pom.xml file.

Ensure you have the latest release of Anypoint Studio 7. If not download the latest.

After that if you still have the issue try creating a new workspace for the project.